# -eris, -oris, -uris?

Tags: declension, noun, third-declension, origin

Much to students' annoyance, nouns ending in *-us* can belong to either the second (*servus*), third (*tempus*), or fourth (*circus*) declensions. I understand the origin of the second and fourth: Proto-Indo-European stems in *-o-* vs *-u-*. But the third-declension *-us* nouns are less predictable:

- tempus → temporis (also *corpus*, *decus*, *nemus*)
- latus → lateris (also *genus*, *funus*, *scelus*)
- jūs → jūris (also *crūs*, *pūs*, *rūs*)

The last of these makes sense to me: the root was originally *jūs*, and the intervocalic *s* became *r* in pre-classical Latin (cf *flōs, flōris*).

But for the other two patterns, why sometimes *e* and sometimes *o*? The two patterns seem very distinct: even nouns of uncertain declension, like *penus, -ī/-ūs/-oris*, never interchange *-eris* and *-oris* forms. What led to this distinction?

Comment: There is at least one noun that varies between *-eris* and *-oris*, though it's not an *-us* noun: *iecur*, gen. *iecinoris / iocineris / iecoris*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual explanation given in historical grammars, e.g. those of Weiss, Sihler, and Buck, is that the *-er-* stems result from regular sound change, while the *-or-* stems result from analogical remodeling on the basis of the nominative/accusative.

A well-known Latin sound change turned all short vowels in word-medial open syllables to *i*. Since short unstressed *ir* is a disfavored sequence in Latin, though, before *r* such vowels became *e* instead. (Compare second-person passive forms like *cap-e-ris*, vs. *cap-i-tur*.) This is how you get the medial vowel of the *lateris* type.

Apparently, though, in some cases the vowel of the nominative/accusative -- which would still have been *o*, e.g. *tempos*, *corpos* -- was restored throughout the declension, giving the *temporis* type. Why this happened in some nouns and not others is unexplained: it's often the case that analogical changes hit some words but miss others for unclear reasons.

This, as I said, is the standard explanation. It is interesting, however, that in three of the four *-oris* examples you list, the consonant before the *o* is a labial. This could be coincidence, of course, but maybe part of the explanation is phonetic, since the presence of a labial could plausibly favor the rounded vowel *o*. It would be interesting to look at the full set of such neuter *s*-stems to see if there are any phonetic patterns of this kind.

Comment: Holt Parker (in Parker 1988) offers a more nuanced explanation: 1. medial weakening (no exceptions); 2. rhotacism; 3. R-lowering. V̌s  > ǐs > ǐr > ěr; cf. NVMISIOS

Comment: As a matter of fact, Tronskii 1960 proposed the same analysis (§117, on page 79), even though Parker 1988 does not mention Tronskii. As the saying goes, everything new is well-forgotten old.