# Extra syllable in "foedus"

Tags: declension

[Foedus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foedus) is both a noun and an adjective. As a noun, it is classified as third declension, since its genitive ends in *-is*: *foederis*.

I am intrigued however on the added "*er*" syllable. Why not *foedis*? Other cases (but not all of them) also have the "*er*" syllable added.

My guess is that this addition is to differentiate between the noun and the adjective. Compare:

> Adjective - Noun
>
> foedis - foederis
>       foede  - foedere
>       foedum - foederum
>       foeda - foedera
>       foedi - foederi

The second column, without the extra "er" syllable, would be just as the adjective. Is this the reason of the added "*er*"? Is this common in Latin?

Comment: Nothing was “added” in the oblique cases. s > r rhotacism

Comment: Note that the adjective is first/second, not third: *foedus, -a, -um*.

Comment: But the stem in Classical Latin is _foeder-_, just like _vetus, veter-_, and similar to _corpus, corpor-_. Draconis' answer gives the historical background.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The noun *foedus* originally (by which I mean late Proto-Italic going into early Latin) looked something like **foidos-*. Note that that's the stem, with no ending attached.

*Proto-Indo-European ablaut patterns would have meant the stem was *foidos- in the nominative and vocative and *foides- in the other cases, but I'm not sure if this ablaut was still relevant in Proto-Italic or if it had been levelled out; this answer is written as if it were already levelled out, for simplicity. The result is the same either way.*

The third-declension endings were then added onto this. (I'm only showing the nominative, genitive, and ablative, but you can extrapolate the rest.)

```
foidos-∅
foidos-es
foidos-e
```

Note that the nominative ending for neuter third-declension nouns is ∅ (that is, nothing at all). Then *rhotacism* applied, changing S between vowels to R.

```
foidos
foidores
foidore
```

Another process turned all short vowels in medial open syllables (i.e. vowels in the middle of a word and not before two consonants) into *i*. [But Latin didn't like *ir*, so this sequence became *er*.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1908/406) Note that this happened no matter what the vowel was, so it doesn't matter if the PIE ablaut was still relevant or not.

```
foidos
foideres
foidere
```

Finally, short *o* in the last syllable of a word turned into *u*, short *e* in closed final syllables turned into *i*, and *oi* was respelled *oe*.

```
foedus
foederis
foedere
```

This led to the noun forms you're familiar with in Classical times.

The adjective *foedus* came from a different source: its stem was actually *foid-* instead of *foidos-*, and the standard first/second endings were tacked onto this.

Comment: foedus is a neuter -s stem, so there was never a second s for the nominative singular ("foidos-s").

Comment: Can we be sure the oblique cases originally had *foidos- ?  It looks parallel to _genus/generis_, which when compared to its Greek cognate γένος/γένεος suggests an original e/o ablaut.

Comment: @fdb D'oh, I thought it was masculine for some reason. Lemme fix that.

Comment: @varro I'm not actually sure; I'm going by what TKR said in the linked answer, but I can't think of any way to distinguish the two cases unfortunately.

Comment: γένος/γένεος can only be explained by ablaut. Likewise Old Church Slavonic slovo/slovese.

Comment: @fdb Oh, I'm not doubting it happens in PIE, I'm wondering if that's relevant in Proto-Italic/Latin given the merging of short vowels, or if there's any way to be sure it wasn't already neutralized in Proto-Italic. Some ablaut patterns are definitely still there in Latin (pater vs patris) but I can't think of any case that would show this one meaningfully.

Comment: Thanks! How common is this in Latin?

Comment: @luchonacho Which part, the -us/-eris pattern? It's quite common: latus/lateris "side", genus/generis "gender", sidus/sideris "star", just off the top of my head.

Comment: The e-grade of the suffix in the weak cases is the most common (and logical) reconstruction. Naturally, it was accented since this a neuter s-stem noun, i.e. it belongs to the proterokinetic (or proterodynamic) accent-ablaut class.

Comment: Also, I assume the declension paradigm is a reconstruction, so gen. sg. should probably have *es, i.e. PIt. *foidéses.

Comment: @AlexB. I'm not too familiar with Proto-Italic declension; at what point (and how) did *es turn into -is?

Comment: @Draconis I assumed you would want an scholarly reference to back up my claim, so here's Weiss 2009/2011: *e > i/_C# (rule I.A.7, page 138), i.e. the raising of e to i before a consonant in a final syllable.  It's usually called "e-raising" or "the raising of e to i". He mentions the following examples, FECED > FECID and SALVTES > salutis.

Comment: @AlexB. Excellent, ty! Not asking for a source so much as for a point in the process, so that I can edit that into the appropriate part of the answer. But the reference is much appreciated!

Comment: As for *es in gen.sg. of 3rd declension nouns specifically, we do have some inscriptional evidence: SALVTES, VENERES, IVNONE[NE]S.

Comment: @varro if anyone has doubts whether the suffix had the e- or o-grade in the weak (oblique) cases, they should read Sihler (page 307). imho he's very convincing.

Comment: @varro I've just found out - accidentally - that Sihler is merely repeating (albeit in English) Leumann et al. 1977 (the latter, as we know, is in German).

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks for the reference.  I don't have access to Leumann, but do have Sihler, and I agree.

Comment: @AlexB. I added a note about the PIE ablaut. Would you be interested in adding an answer to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1907/406) as well, which currently has nothing about ablaut in it? I'm curious if the ablaut has any effect on the difference between -eris S-stems like *latus* and -oris S-stems like *corpus*. TKR's analogical explanation seems convincing, but then again I don't know anything really about ablaut in noun declension.