# If arm is 'arma', why is unarmed 'inermis' and not 'inarmis'?

Tags: etymology, spanish, negation

I came across the Spanish word '[inerme](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LSuw8Oa)', which comes from Latin *inermis* and means *unarmed*.

Since the Latin word for arm is 'arma' and the preffix 'in' indicates negation, it is clear that the form 'inermis' is just 'in-' + 'arma', so I wonder: why does it get *in**e**rmis* and not *in**a**rmis*?

Comment: Welcome to the hood, old friend!

Comment: The answer is here https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/eris-oris-uris/1908#1908

Comment: Allow me to grant you a bronze badge for your question, my friend. :-)

Comment: @Charlie so nice to feel your kindness also in this site!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is one of many examples of Latin vowel reduction in word-internal syllables. The basic pattern is that short vowels in word-internal syllables were reduced: the resulting vowel in Classical Latin varies depending on the phonological context, and sometimes on the vowel. In *inermis*, the vowel is in a closed syllable, which is a context where a reduced short *-a-* typically turned into *-e-*.

Another example is *in**e**ptus* from ***a***ptus.

Vowel reduction was not an automatic process in Classical Latin, so there are also examples of words that don't change short *-a-* into *-e-* upon prefixation, e.g. *ĭn**ă**mābĭlis.*

Comment: I think it makes a difference whether the syllable is open or closed. Reduction seems to be more common in (but not restricted to) closed syllables.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Vowels in internal open syllables were reduced also (to -i- in most contexts; to -e- before -r-, or sometimes before a mute + r cluster; sometimes to -u- before a labial consonant).

Comment: The standard example of my Latin teacher was in + amicus = inimicus. Same thing there.

Answer (score 7):

All credit of this answer goes to sumelic. I just found further support for his hypothesis, of which I was not aware.

[This article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41219151) states:

> Bader (1960: 236) remarks that words prefixed by privative in- (<
>    **en*- < **n*-) and *dis*- frequently show vowel reduction (cf. Pultrová
>    2006: 73, 102-103), such as *inimīcus* 'unfriendly' (vs. *amīcus* 'friendly')  and *difficilis* 'difficult' (vs. *facilis* 'easy'). The list of examples is  lengthened by *inficētus* 'boorish' (vs. *infacētus*; cf. *perfacētus* 'very
>    clever'); *īnsipiēns* 'unwise' [P1.+], whose finite forms (**insipiō*) are
>    missing in Plautine Latin (cf. *insapiēns* [Catul.]; *persapiēntis* 'very
>    wise' [Cic], *nesapius* 'ignorant' [Petr.+]); ***inermis*** 'unarmed' (vs. *arma* 'weapons'); *iners* 'inactive' (vs. *ars* 'art, skill'); *dīmidius* 'half (< **dis-*; vs. *mēdius* 'central', cf. rare forms like *intermedius*, *permedius*, *submedius*; see Ernout and Meillet 1985: 393); *displiceō* 'displease' (vs. *placeō* 'please', cf. *complaceō* 'take the fancy', *perplaceō* 'be thoroughly pleasing'); etc. (but cf. *illepidus* 'lacking grace', *inanimus* 'lifeless'). These forms commonly possess a negative sense due to their prefixes. The *i*-vocalism may thus be phonetically strengthened by a certain emphasis, as Pulgram (1975: 108-109) points out, whereby the
>    following elements presumably underwent vowel reduction, and were
>    influenced by the *i*-vocalism.

References in paragraph:

- Bader, Fr. (1960): Apophonie et recomposition dans les composés. RPh 86:
- Ernout, A and A. Meillet (1985): *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue latine: histoire des mots.* 4th, rev. and enl. ed. Paris: Librairie C. Klincksieck
- Pulgram, E. (1975): *Latin-Romance Phonology: Prosodies and Metrics.* Munich:
  Wilhelm Fink Verl
- Pultrová, L. (2006): *The Vocalism of Latin Medial Syllables*. Prague: Univerzita Karlova
  v Praze / Nakladatelstvi Karolinum.

---

Similarly, pages 222-3 of [this (old) book](https://archive.org/details/latinlanguagehis00linduoft) state:

> Unaccented Latin ă in the posttonic syllable became at first *ĕ*, 
>   except before *l* and labials, where it became *ŏ*. This *ĕ* became, 
>   perhaps about the end of the third century B.C., *ĭ* in syllables 
>   not long by position (except when it preceded *r*), and before *ng*; while this *o* became *u* or the *ü*-sound, which in most cases passed 
>   into *ĭ* at the close of the Republican period. Thus the compound 
>   of *ab* and *cado* became *accĕdo* (so spelt by Ennius), then *accĭdo*; 
>   from *in* and *arma* we have the compound ***inermis***; from *sub* 
>   and *rapio* first **surropio* probably, then *surrŭpio* (Plaut.), then 
>   *surripio*', from *ex* and *frango*, *effringo* (see ch, iii. 18). Final Latin *ă* probably became *ĕ*, and might be dropped (see ch. iii. 37).

Comment: If final ă became ĕ, why didn't that apply to the nominative singular in the first declension? Was there some other counterfeeding process?

Comment: @Draconis I know nothing of linguistic theory, but isn't this an issue of "compound" words only? Are you asking why not **every** final ă became ĕ? As in _rosĕ_? That's a way more dramatic change, imo.

Comment: @Draconis, the 1st declension nom. sg. was originally -ā, and shortened for not entirely clear reasons; presumably this shortening postdates non-initial vowel weakening. There are some other examples of final short vowels which "should have" gone to *-i* but didn't because they were originally long, e.g. *male, ego*.

Comment: Vowel weakening doesn't only occur in compound words -- for example, *caput / capitis* is the same phenomenon.

Comment: @sumelic You're right, sorry -- word-final short vowels behave differently from medial ones. *Male* is, rather, an example of unexpected final vowel quantity (because of iambic shortening).