# Inars > iners: how is this change called?

Tags: language-evolution, phonetics

What linguistic process is illustrated by changing /a/ into /e/ in *inars/iners*? Assimilation? Why has it taken place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If arm is 'arma', why is unarmed 'inermis' and not 'inarmis'?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/if-arm-is-arma-why-is-unarmed-inermis-and-not-inarmis) luchonacho’s answer has a quote that mentions *iners.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [vowel reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction).
Basically, a vowel that loses emphasis becomes weaker.
This is very typical with one-syllable prefixes:
*ars > iners*, *facere > efficere*.
It can also happen due to inflection, as in *tango > tetigi* (from stem *tag-* with nasal augment in present stem and reduplication in perfect stem).

Old Latin had initial stress and therefore prefixes move stress away.
When stress is lost, a short vowel tends to become weaker.
The stress system changed later, but the vowel changes stuck.

Comment: I've always thought of it as vowel raising: early Latin raised most unstressed vowels (a -> e or i, e -> i, o -> u)