# Why is it Iuppiter rather than Iuppater?

Tags: etymology, morphology

Iuppiter comes from the vocative of the Indo-European *dyeus-patēr, cognate with Zeus in Greek. However, as *a > a in Latin and 'pater' survives elsewhere in Latin, one would expect Iuppater. How has the /a/ changed to an /i/?

Comment: "A well-known Latin sound change turned all short vowels in word-medial open syllables to i"  (TKR) https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1908/39

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're absolutely right that PIE `*a` gives *Old* Latin `/a/`. But somewhere between Old Latin and Classical Latin, *vowel reduction* happened.

Basically, Old Latin stress was always on the first syllable. So short vowels in other (non-stressed) syllables tended to get reduced, sort of like how English keeps the *i* in "combine" but reduces it in "combination".

In *most* instances, the reduced vowels became `/i/`. This is why `/i/` appears in lots of prefixed verbs: the *a* in *faciō* is reduced to the *i* in *afficiō*, for example. (It's not always an *i*: consonant clusters and *r*, for example, tend to turn it into an *e* instead, which is why the participle of *afficiō* is *affectus*.)

That's what happened in this case. In Old Latin, the word was something like *Jup-pater*, from Proto-Italic *Djou-patēr*; vowel reduction then turned the *a* into an *i*, giving *Juppiter*.

(Sometimes it's written *Jūpiter*, sometimes *Juppiter*; this alternation comes from the "littera rule", named for *lītera~littera*.)

Comment: As a small quibble, *Iuppiter* is thought to come from a vocative rather than a nominative, so *diou-pater.

Comment: @TKR Oops, you're right! Changed.